# Wrong file linked: libcap.so.1

Tags: compilation

I'm getting this error in my application:

```
# bin/ladvd -h
bin/ladvd: error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.1: cannot open
           shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My system I'm installing on has /lib/libcap.so.2, but the system I am compiling with (RHEL5) only has libcap.so.1, so it is linking incorrectly. I could get an Ubuntu system to compile it on if I needed to go that route.

On my Devil-Linux system, I can't change anything on the filesystem, except for /root, /etc, and /var.

I would just link /lib/libcap.so.1 to the appropriate file if I could, but I can't change the filesystem without a huge headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a link in another directory and then add this directory into  `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  with such bash command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Good deal. I just put that line in ~/.bash_profile, and it will load up when I log in.

Comment: @bradlis7, also, i must say, that using such symlinks is a Hack, and it can break anything. Also, you can consider of linkink to this (only this) library statically, if you have one (change at linking step from "-lcap" to "..path.../libcap.a)